# Msg erro em caso de erro de digitacao JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Queria inserir uma msg de erro, que nao seja em alert, quando o usuário digitar menos ou mais que os caracteres pré definidos no jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mascaraTelefone').mask('(99) 99999-9999');
    $('.mascaraCep').mask('99999-999');
    $('.mascaraCpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
    $('.mascaraCnh').mask('99999999999');
    $('.mascaraPlaca').mask ('AAA-9999')

    $('.mascaraCnh').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(value);
        console.log(value.length);
        if(value.length < 10) {
            alert('O campo CNH deve ter 11 caracteres');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de forma mais dinâmica, sem ter que criar um evento change para cada elemento. Com apenas um evento `change` você já consegue tratar todos os elementos, basta colocar uma classe igual em cada elemento que você quer que seja ouvido pelo change. Por, exemplo, coloquei a class `mask` em cada input:

```
<input type="text" data-label="CNH" class="mascaraCpf mask">
```

Adicionei também um atributo `data-label` que será o nome do campo a apresentar na mensagem de erro.

O plugin Mask adiciona em cada input um atributo `maxlength` de acordo com a formatação aplicada. Desta forma você consegue saber de forma automática quantos caracteres aquele campo deve ter, e tudo já fica de forma automática no evento change. Se forem digitados menos caracteres necessários no campo, você adiciona uma div após o campo com a mensagem de erro. Se o campo foi digitado corretamente, a mensagem é removida, veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mascaraTelefone').mask('(00) 99999-9999');
    $('.mascaraCep').mask('99999-999');
    $('.mascaraCpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
    $('.mascaraCnh').mask('99999999999');
    $('.mascaraPlaca').mask ('AAA-9999')

    $('.mask').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var maxLen = $(this).attr("maxlength");

         // se não existe a div de erro após o elemento, adiciona
        if(value.length < maxLen && !$(this).next(".erro").length) {
            $(this).after('<div class="erro">O campo '+$(this).data("label")+' deve ter '+maxLen+' caracteres</div>');
        }else{
           // se já existe, remove
           $(this).next(".erro").remove();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.erro{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
Telefone:<br>
<input type="text" data-label="Telefone" class="mascaraTelefone mask">
<br>
CEP:<br>
<input type="text" data-label="CEP" class="mascaraCep mask">
<br>
CPF:<br>
<input type="text" data-label="CNH" class="mascaraCpf mask">
```

Observe que alterei a formatação do campo telefone de `(99)` para `(00)` porque (não sei o motivo, tem que ler a [doc do plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)) com `(99)` não estava funcionando corretamente.